# Avoiding overlap in rendering of GraphPlot

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to visualize some 'graphs' (i.e. the mathematical objects with nodes and edges) using GraphPlot[].  I am defining the nodes using objects such as

```
node[1] = Column[{"NGC", "1"}, Center]
```

and then setting the option VertexLabeling->True.  I am also using VerticCoordinateRules with terms like

```
node[1]->{Automatic, 2}
```

Overall, I'm happy with my results except for the fact that the nodes are rendered overlapping one another (see the image below).  I have tried messing around with DataRange option, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Here is an example.

```
graphNodes["Lys"] = {
 Column[{"AAA", "0.29"}, Center] -> Column[{"1CU", 11}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAA", "0.29"}, Center] -> Column[{"3UC", 14}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAA", "0.29"}, Center] -> Column[{"3UG", 9}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAA", "0.29"}, Center] -> Column[{"3UU", 7}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAA", "0.29"}, Center] -> Column[{"CUU", 14}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAA", "0.29"}, Center] -> Column[{"GUU", 10}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAA", "0.29"}, Center] -> Column[{"NGU", 4}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAA", "0.29"}, Center] -> Column[{"PAP", 2}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAG", "0   "}, Center] -> Column[{"3UU", 7}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAG", "0   "}, Center] -> Column[{"CAU", 5}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAG", "0   "}, Center] -> Column[{"CCU", 1}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAG", "0   "}, Center] -> Column[{"CUC", 2}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAG", "0   "}, Center] -> Column[{"CUU", 14}, Center], 
 Column[{"AAG", "0   "}, Center] -> Column[{"GUU", 10}, Center]};

nodeCoordinates["Lys"] = {Column[{"1CU", 11}, Center] -> {Automatic, 0}, 
 Column[{"3UC", 14}, Center] -> {Automatic, 0}, 
 Column[{"3UG", 9}, Center] -> {Automatic, 0}, 
 Column[{"3UU", 7}, Center] -> {Automatic, 4}, 
 Column[{"AAA", "0.29"}, Center] -> {Automatic, 2}, 
 Column[{"AAG", "0   "}, Center] -> {Automatic, 2}, 
 Column[{"CAU", 5}, Center] -> {Automatic, 0}, 
 Column[{"CCU", 1}, Center] -> {Automatic, 0}, 
 Column[{"CUC", 2}, Center] -> {Automatic, 0}, 
 Column[{"CUU", 14}, Center] -> {Automatic, 4}, 
 Column[{"GUU", 10}, Center] -> {Automatic, 0}, 
 Column[{"NGU", 4}, Center] -> {Automatic, 0}, 
 Column[{"PAP", 2}, Center] -> {Automatic, 0}};

GraphPlot[graphNodes[myAA], VertexLabeling -> True, 
 VertexCoordinateRules -> nodeCoordinates[myAA]]
```

And here's what I get,
[image: PlotGraph[] with overlapping nodes]

Comment: Add `ImageSize->...` and adjust as needed, or calculate specific coordinates and use them...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ciao, but I already tried using ImageSize and it generally doesn't work, especially since I am rendering multiple graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Either calculate correct / specific coordinates to effect a desired spacing, or use `ImageSize` option, e.g.

```
GraphPlot[graphNodes["Lys"], VertexLabeling -> True, 
 VertexCoordinateRules -> nodeCoordinates["Lys"], ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ciao, but one of the main reasons I am using GraphPlot[] is so I don't have to try and figure out the exact x-axis coordinates.  I am doing this for 18 different amino acids and so I'd like a solution that doesn't involve me having to  tweak each plot by setting different ImageSize options.

Answer (score 1):

Changing ImageSize with one number changes both the height and width of the figure.  In order to preserve the height across differen datasets (which is in retrospect one aspect I want) I have found a reasonable solution that involves setting the Y aspect of ImageSize to a fixed value and the X aspect to a value based on the number of nodes at the bottom of the graph..

```
ImageSize -> {20*numNodes, 200}
```

I also realized one could set ImageSize ->numNodes and make AspectRatio->2/numNodes and get a similar effect.

My next goal is to figure out how to minimize the overlap in edges going to the bottom row (not an issue with "Lys" but a real problem with some other amino acids).

Thanks for your help @ciao.

Mike